# Python pread/pwrite Only On Unix?

Tags: python

Is the Python documentation accurate that os.pread/pwrite are only supported on Unix, not Windows? I ask what seems like a blindingly obvious question because Windows has supported these features (by different names) for nearly 20 years prior to the functions being added to Python, and 5 years prior to Unix (POSIX, specifically) supporting them.

Comment: Since Python is free software, propose a patch to fulfill your wish to the Python community (and study the source code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the documentation is correct. You can see the source in [`posixmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/posixmodule.c), or just try it out yourself.

The reason for this is that the `os` module works in terms of POSIX-style file descriptors, as returned by `open`. Windows does support POSIX-style file descriptors, but does not support the full POSIX API with them.

The Windows-specific `HANDLE`-based API does have a lot of similar functionality—in some cases more, in some cases less, in some cases just different. And for high-level wrappers like `io` for text files, `asyncio` for reactor loops, `shutil` for filesystem operations, `multiprocessing` for pipes, etc., Python often does use the Win32 API instead of using the incomplete POSIX API on Windows.

But for the low-level functionality in `os`, which mostly maps each function directly to a native function call, that kind of wrapper would be very difficult to do, especially without forcing everyone to use a very weak lowest common denominator.

This is the same reason Python doesn't support anything but Windows in `os.startfile`—even though macOS has had similar functionality for even longer than Windows, and Linux has had it for many years now via xdg, neither has anything exactly like what Windows has.

(Of course, as Basile Starynkevitch implies in a comment, there are cases where it *would* be possible to mirror an API perfectly, and it just hasn't happened because nobody's written the code for it. That was the case for `os.replace` on Windows up to Python 3.3, for example.)

Comment: Hmm. Is the sole reason for that that open/read/write support text mode, or are there additional things you mention that the WinAPI file functions don't support?

Comment: @JustinOlbrantz I’m not use I understand your question. Are you talking about the POSIX functions open/read/write, the Windows POSIX-emulation function _open/_read/_write, or the Python os module functions, which work in terms of an integer file descriptor, or Python’s builtin open and the read and write methods on the file objects it returns? The latter isn’t relevant here, and Python’s text mode is built purely in Python, not relying on the OS at all.

Comment: @JustinOlbrantz Meanwhile, POSIX file descriptors can, for example, be used to throw files and sockets together into the same `select`, passed as command line arguments to child processes, keep a reference to an open file even after you delete or even replace it in the filesystem, represent directories and be used to open/stat/etc. a file in that directory, etc. Windows can’t do those things with POSIX-style fds or even with Win32 file handles—but it can do things with file handles like completion ports, deriving less capable handles to pass to children, and exclusive locks enforced by the fs.

Answer (score 2):

The real condition is - is `HAVE_PREAD` exported?

Here's the relevant fragment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4a172ccc739065bb658c75e8929774a8e94af9e9/Modules/posixmodule.c#L8422

Since MSVC++ doesn't provide `pread` but uses [`ReadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for this, it's not exported via the `os` module.

It does seem to be exported in [overlapped](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/55edd0c185ad2d895b5d73e47d67049bc156b654/Modules/overlapped.c#L731) though. You can find it in `_winapi`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `_winapi` is intentionally left undocumented. IIRC, the main reason is that it's very incomplete, basically providing exactly what's needed for a few public modules like `asyncio` for the console code and no more, so it's only useful for going under the covers of those modules; if you actually want to build anything with the Win32 API, you're better off getting `pywin32`. But I may not be remembering how that discussion turned out.