# Are Python Unix-only APIs supported under WSL?

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Some Python APIs, such as [`os.pread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pread), are documented with availability "Unix", and indeed they are [not visible when using native Windows Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50902714/python-pread-pwrite-only-on-unix).

Are they supported in Python installed via WSL (Windows subsystem for Linux)?

Comment: Easy to test, isn't it?

Comment: In short, most likely, yes.

Comment: @KlausD. why didn't you?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3929826

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299411/2351099

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  For most intents and purposes, when you run code through [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) (WSL2, at least), you are running code through the OS that you installed via WSL.

Proof of [running under WSL](https://www.scivision.dev/python-detect-wsl/):

```
>>> import platform; platform.uname().release
'5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2'
```

Test data:

```
>>> with open('temp.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
...     f.write('foo\nbar\nbaz\n')
...
12
```

Test results:

```
>>> import os

>>> f = os.open('temp.txt', os.O_RDONLY)

>>> os.pread(f, 4, 0)
b'foo\n'

>>> os.pread(f, 4, 4)
b'bar\n'

>>> os.pread(f, 4, 0)
b'foo\n'

>>> os.close(f)
```